# How to call a function only when scroll to a certain position?

Tags: java, android

I want to call a function only when user scroll to a certain position. Currently I am doing the following:

```
view.addOnScrollChangeListener(){
     int[] locA = v1.getLocationOnScreen(); // it gives x & y location 
     int[] locB = v2.getLocationOnScreen(); // it gives x & y location 
     if(locA[1] == threshold) callFunctionA();
     if(locB[1] == threshold) callFunctionB();
}
```

Problem is, it never calls `callFunctionA() or callFunctionB` if user scroll too fast. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using scrollview as the scrolling container?

Comment: yes, v1 and v2 are views that inside the scrolling view

Comment: You can add your both views to a recyclerview and get the scroll position

Comment: i already can get the scroll position for both view, but i want to call a function exactly once when user pass the threshold

Answer (score 0):

This should work. This triggers if you scroll past a certain point and will happen again if you scroll before the threshold again.

```
boolean funcACalled = false;
boolean funcBCalled = false;
view.addOnScrollChangeListener(){
   int[] locA = v1.getLocationOnScreen(); // it gives x & y location 
   int[] locB = v2.getLocationOnScreen(); // it gives x & y location 
   if(locA[1] > threshold && !funcACalled){
       callFunctionA();
       funcACalled = true;
   }
   if(locB[1] > threshold && !funcBCalled){
       callFunctionB(); 
       funcBCalled = true;
   }
   if(locA[1] < threshold) funcACalled = false;
   if(locB[1] < threshold) funcBCalled = false;
}
```